# How to check if the user has authorized the app in pinterest

Tags: pinterest, authorize

I have a code which helps me to successfully authorize my application by pinterest.

My application gets listed in my pinterest app settings, but each time I login, pinterest asks me to authorize the app.
Is there a way to avoid it ? Can I check if my app is authorized by the user and skip this procedure every time I try to login with pinterest?
I use Oauth 2.0 for authentication.